# About multi threading

Tags: java, multithreading

How to kill the thread?
.....
How to restart them again in multi threading?

Comment: There is Thread.stop(): http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop() , but it is not recommended that you do that: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Comment: The actual page that explains the dangers of thread primitives is http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Comment: @chetans, you should rewrite this so it's more specific and makes more sense.

Comment: Best way to kill a thread is by drowning. Threads can't swim.

Comment: What do you mean by 'restart' a thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i wrap my worker threads up in their own class and use a terminated property to kill the thread proc loop.

sorry i dont have a java version to hand right now but you should get the idea from this
http://pastie.org/880516

```
using System.Threading; 

namespace LoaderDemo
{
    class ParserThread
    {
        private bool m_Terminated;
        private AutoResetEvent m_Signal;
        private string m_FilePath;
        ...

        public ParserThread(AutoResetEvent signal, string filePath)
        {
            m_Signal = signal; 
            m_FilePath = filePath;

            Thread thrd = new Thread(this.ThreadProc);
            thrd.Start(); 
        }

        public bool Terminated { 
            set { m_Terminated = value; } 
        }

        private Guid Parse(ref string s)
        {
            //parse the string s and return a populated Guid object
            Guid g = new Guid();

            // do stuff...

            return g;
        }

        private void ThreadProc()
        {
            TextReader tr = null;
            string line = null;
            int lines = 0;

            try
            {
                tr = new StreamReader(m_FilePath);
                while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (m_Terminated) break;

                    Guid g = Parse(ref line);
                    m_GuidList.Add(g);
                    lines++;
                }

                m_Signal.Set(); //signal done

            }
            finally
            {
                tr.Close();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since your post is tagged "Java," I have a good idea of what you are saying. Let's say you start a thread by doing:

```
Thread foo = new Thread(someRunnable);
foo.start();
```

Now that `destroy` and friends are deprecated, you need a way to kill the thread. Luckily for you, there has always been the concept of "interrupts." Simply change your runnable so that, on interrupt, it exits. Then call the thread's `interrupt` method.

```
foo.interrupt();
```

If you wrote your Runnable to handle this correctly, it will stop whatever it is doing and terminate.

Answer (score 3):

`Thread.stop()` kills a thread, but you definitely **don't** want to do this (see the API documentation for an explanation why).  `Thread.interrupt()` sends an asynchronous notification to a thread, so that it can shut itself gracefully.

For a comprehensive text on Java multithreading, I recommend B. Goetz, *Java Concurrency in Practice*, Addison-Wesley Professional.

Comment: Thread.stop() is kind of like putting a car traveling at 60mph in park to stop it...definitely stops it, but you're going to leave a sad, sad trail of twisted metal along the way and your car won't ever quite be the same ;-)

Comment: also, Thread.interrupt wont always interrupt a thread waiting on IO. if youre serious about designing for interruption you need a way to forcibly close any IO streams your target thread might be waiting on

Answer (score 3):

The preferred way for a [`Thread`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) to die is for the execution of the `run` method to go to completion:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    // Do something...

    // Thread will end gracefully here.
  }
}
```

Once a thread gracefully dies in the example above, the `Thread` cannot be restarted. (Trying to call [`Thread.start`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()) on a thread that has already been started will cause an [`IllegalThreadStateException`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalThreadStateException.html).)

In that case, one can make another instance of the thread and call `start` on that.

Probably a good place to get more information on threading would be [Lesson: Concurrency](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) from [The Java Tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to kill a thread is to set up a flag for the thread to watch. Program the thread to exit when it sees the flag is set to true. There's no way to restart a killed thread.

Comment: The best way to kill a thread is to call Thread.interrupt() and have the thread also monitor its interrupt status periodically. Adding yet another boolean is entirely redundant.

Comment: In addition to what EJP said, the hand-rolled flag doesn't play well with executors.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start, stop, restart threads at will, maybe using the Java 5 concurrency package would be a good idea. You can have an Executor that will do a bit of work, and when you need that bit of work to be done again, you can just re-schedule it to be done in the executor.

Answer (score 0):

*Regarding your first query on killing thread:*

You can find more details about topic in below SE questions:

[How to properly stop the Thread in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961714/how-to-properly-stop-the-thread-in-java)

[How can I kill a thread? without using stop();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915156/how-can-i-kill-a-thread-without-using-stop)

[How to start/stop/restart a thread in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881714/how-to-start-stop-restart-a-thread-in-java)

Regarding your second query of re-starting thread, it's not possible in java.

You can find below details in documentation [page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)

> public void start()
>
> Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls the run method of this thread.
>
> The result is that two threads are running concurrently: the current thread (which returns from the call to the start method) and the other thread (which executes its run method).

*It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.*

Instead of plain Threads, you can use advanced concurrent API for thread life cycle management. Have a look at this post for ExecutorService details :

[How to properly use Java Executor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33596079/how-to-properly-use-java-executor/33596230#33596230)