# Blue-tooth file not sent error

Tags: android, file, bluetooth

I am trying to send a file from my application on android phone to other devices (they may or may not be be android phones).

my whole code for sending the file is :

```
try{
            File dir = getCacheDir();
            File f;
            try {
                f = File.createTempFile("card", ".Xcard", dir);

                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("*/*");
                i.putExtra(i.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(f));
                startActivity(i);


            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            }catch(Exception e){

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

But my file is not being sent to the phone??
What is wrong in the code?
Is it because the receiving phone does not recognize my ".Xcard" file?

But I don't think that is the problem 
because i tried sending "apk" file to the other device and it received even though it doesn't understand the apk file. (i am trying with the non-android phone).

Then why not the file that I am sending being not-sent? is it because it is created in Cache directory?

Comment: What happens? Does an activity appear that allows the user to choose where to send the file? Maybe the file is being ignored because it is empty -- have you tried writing content to it?

Comment: no I havent written any content to it , I will check if it is sent with some content.

Comment: I added this code:  OutputStream op = new FileOutputStream(f);
     int oneByte = 1;
     op.write(oneByte);
     op.close(); but it is not working

Comment: The code looks ok -- but what *happens*? Does an activity appear? A dialog? An error message? Nothing at all?

Comment: I am getting an error saying "file filename was not sent to bluetoothdevicename"

Comment: A dialog appears for selection :whether i want to send file using bluetooth, gmail etc, then i select bluetooth, then the al the devices in the range are shown and then i select the required device

Comment: after i select it , a toast appears "sending file to device name"

Comment: and then again the toast with the error...... basically it is using the default bluetooth application provided by the system

Comment: Does it work if you choose "Send by email?"

Comment: right now i cant test it using e-mail , can you do it ?? thats the only code i am using on the onCLick method of my button

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29538/discussion-between-neerajdorle-and-tony-the-pony)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/html");
File f = new File(root + "/bluetooth/test2.html");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(f));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send page"));
```

The difference is in create the file in the bluetooth directory.