# Stop child threads in a runnable jar

Tags: linux, multithreading, executable-jar

I have a runnable jar file in which I run the Start.java file.

Start.java spawns 3 child threads. How can I kill the Start thread & the child threads?

Here is Start.java

```
public class Start {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ListenersManager.start();
        PollPatientPortalManager.start();
        PollHISManager.start();
    }
}
```

ListenersManager, PollPatientPortalManager & PollHISManager all extend `Thread`.

Comment: Do you want to kill from the command line or from Java?

Comment: I would prefer Java. But if that's not possible, then command line is also fine.

Answer (score 1):

The start thread is the `main` thread. To "kill" it, you just need to return from `main()`.

For the other threads, you can call `.destroy()` and `.stop()` on them. Note that these methods are rude and can cause bugs (that's why they are deprecated).

The correct solution is to define a "signal" (like a shared flag) which the threads check once in a while. To stop them, send the signal.

To kill all threads from the command line, just kill the process (see `man kill`).

Related:

- [How to properly stop the Thread in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961714/how-to-properly-stop-the-thread-in-java)
- [Communication between parent and child thread in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398064/communication-between-parent-and-child-thread-in-java)

Comment: But the thing is I will make a runnable jar. I will run the start thread on jar startup. But there is no way to stop the child threads from the jar itself. So the only way is through the command line. I want to write a script for stopping the threads. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The clean way is to listen to a signal in the `main` thread. For example, you can open a socket and wait for connections. A command line tool can then connect to the socket and send commands, ask for the current status, etc. That way, you can cleanly shut down.