# Closing resources when thread is finished in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have a thread that uses network port for communication. I added 
cancel() method to stop the execution and close network resources ([How to properly stop the Thread in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961714/how-to-properly-stop-the-thread-in-java))

```
private class ServerThread extends Thread {
        int portNumber;
        String serverAddress = null;

        public ServerThread(String serverAddress, int portNumber) {
            super();
            this.serverAddress = "localhost";
            this.portNumber = portNumber;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ServerSocket listener;
            Socket socket;
            try {
                listener = new ServerSocket(this.portNumber);
                socket = listener.accept();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        socket.getInputStream()));
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),
                        true);

                while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    String input = in.readLine();
                    if (input != null) {
                        out.println(input);
                        System.out.println("Hi:" + input);
                    }
                } // end of while loop
                System.out.println("OUT"); <-- ???
                socket.close(); <-- ???
                listener.close(); <-- ???
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }

        public void cancel() {
            System.out.println("cancel called");
            interrupt();
        }
    }
```

The issue is that when I execute the ServerThread, and send cancel() message to finish the execution, it seems like that the three lines of code never executed: `System.out.println("OUT"); socket.close(); listener.close();`.

It also seems like that I don't need to send cancel() message to finish the thread.

```
ServerThread s = new ServerThread(serverAddress, serverPortNumber);
s.start();
...
s.cancel(); // ???
```

What's the recommended way of closing resources used by threads?
Don't I have to close resources when thread is not used anymore? Or everything is just automatically processed?

### ADDED

It seems like that the thread is killed automatically as this code just works.

```
            while(true) {
                String input = in.readLine();

                if (input != null) {
                    System.out.println("Received:" + input);
                    out.println(input);
                }
            } // end of while loop
            /* System.out.println("OUT");
            socket.close();
            listener.close(); */
```

Comment: Don't `interrupt()` it. Implement a clean stop.

Comment: Where are you calling `cancel()` from? It interrupts the _current_ `Thread`. i.e. the `Thread` the calls `cancel()` not your `ServerThread`.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis - I'm not sure what `a clean stop` means, but I tried s.close() to have a warning that it is a deprecated method.

Comment: @Boris the Spider - It is invoked from other thread. BTW, it should have been `interrupt()`, not `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();`. I updated my post.

Comment: You should be exiting your read loop if readLine() reruns null, and closing the socket at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thread#interrupt() will not interrupt the blocking I/O call on the socket. Try setting a "stop" flag and closing the socket in the cancel() method instead, and deal with the exception and check the flag in the while loop.

[InterruptibleChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/InterruptibleChannel.html)s reacts on the interrupt call, but not "old fashioned" socket streams.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 7 you can use the `try (resource) {} catch` idiom like this:

```
try (final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()))) {
  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    process(line);
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will guarantee that the stream is closed properly once the try block is left. No matter what happens inside or how the try/catch terminates.

Comment: I would also add that the code should be using the concurrency framework introduced over a decade ago. There is no need to extend `Thread` and handle thread lifecycle management. Let the `Executor` do that for you.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. The executor can do everything a thread can do, just more convenient.