# Java Thread.stop() vs Thread.interrupt()

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following code:

```
renderThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            System.out.println("Number: " + i);
        }
    }
});

renderThread.start();

try {
    Thread.sleep(100);
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

renderThread.interrupt(); //It should stop, but it does not stop.
```

`renderThread.interrupt()` does not interrupt the thread, it continues to run. If I replace `renderThread.interrupt()` with `.stop()`, then the thread stops. However, `.stop()` is deprecated.
Then, what is the proper way of stopping a thread, if `stop` is deprecated and `interrupt` does not work?

Comment: Why do you think that calling `interrupt` would _stop_ the thread`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to properly stop the Thread in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961714/how-to-properly-stop-the-thread-in-java)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Because, colloquially, "interrupting something" and "stopping something" are synonymous .. I'm not say it's what it *does* (and the documentation is a good place to start unwinding the assumption), but the name is loaded.

Answer (score 27):

When you call interrupt() it triggers a boolean flag which tells the run function it should stop.  That is why I usually write my run functions like this.

```
void run()
{
    while(!Thread.interrupted())
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Just because you call interrupt doesn't mean the thread will stop immediately or at all.  It depends on what is in the run function.

Comment: So it means, that after an interrupt event happens and the code reaches the end of the `run()`, then the thread automatically ceases to exist?

Comment: Yes. All far as I know threads should only stop when run exits.  Interrupting run just lets it know it should exit as soon as possible.  The problem with calling stop() is that say run() had to do some cleanup like close a stream then this would not happen.

Comment: I think this solution cannot solve the question here. When the renderThread  executes the task, it has no chance to check Thread.interrupted().

Comment: if you have `sleep` method in your thread, you will have to call `interrupt` method in this thread in `try...catch (InterruptedException)`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36258705/7767664

Answer (score 6):

To really push the point why you shouldnt use `Thread.stop()`?

Doug Lea recently mentioned that Thread.stop will be the ***first de-implemented method for Java*** come Java 8.

His response to this comment from someone:

> Also, one other thing synchronized has going for it is it handles
>   async aborts of threads (I.e. thread.stop()).  I know stop() is
>   deprecated and all, but you never know.

Was:

> But you do know! As of JDK8, Thread.stop is really gone. It is the
>   first deprecated method to have actually been de-implemented. It now
>   just throws UnsupportedOperationException.

http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2013-December/012028.html

Answer (score 5):

You should take a look at this article:
http://10kloc.wordpress.com/2013/03/03/java-multithreading-steeplechase-stopping-threads/

Basically you shouldn't STOP a thread (unsafe), but interrupt it.
What you're missing is making the thread handle the interruption.

Answer (score 3):

> renderThread.interrupt() does not interrupt the thread, it continues
>   to run.

- If the thread is executing and `interrupt()` is invoked it's interrupt status is set.
- If this thread is blocked in an invocation one of  `wait` methods of the Object class, or of the `Thread.join` and `Thread.sleep` methods of this class then its *interrupt status will be cleared* and it will receive an `InterruptedException`.

*For example:*

```
Thread t = new Thread()
      {
          public void run()
          {
              try {
                  for(int i=0; i<10000;i++)
                      System.out.println("Is interrupTed? "+this.isInterrupted());

                  Thread.sleep(200);
              } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                  Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
              }

          }
      };
      t.start();
      t.interrupt();
    }
```

The above code, I have used a `for` loop to intercept the interrput flag with [`isInterrupted()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted%28%29) function and printed it. As `t.interrupt()` is invoked, `isInterrupted()` will return `true` which you will see in the console. As soon as it reaches the `Thread.sleep(miliTime)` you will see that `InterruptedException` is caught which was thrown as described above.

**Stopping a thread:**

you could make use of this `isInterrupted()` flag check if an `interrupt()` was invoked on it and return from the execution:

*For example:*

```
Thread t = new Thread()
      {
          public void run()
          {
              long executeTime = System.currentTimeMillis() ;
              int i = 0;    
              for(; i<10000 && !this.isInterrupted();i++)
                      System.out.println("Is interrupted? "+this.isInterrupted());

               System.out.println("Was Interrupted? "+this.isInterrupted()
                                  +" after cycle: "+ i);
               System.out.println("Time it gets Executed: "
                                  +(System.currentTimeMillis() - executeTime+" ms"));

          }
      };
      t.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
      t.interrupt();
```

While running the above code: i have sent the main thread to sleep for `200` inside the static main function to allow the started thread `t` to run for some time. Then i invoked
`t.interrupt()` on it which causes the `for` loop to stop and print a output as following:

```
Was Interrupted? true after cycle: 1477
Time it gets Executed: 258 ms
```

Which indicates that the `for` loop has `1148` iteration before `t.interrupt();` was invoked in the `main` function.

Please read the documentation of [**`Thread.interrupt()`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) function for more details.

Answer (score 3):

All You need do to interrupt the current thread or terminate the running process of the thread is to 
add the below statement within you catch block

```
try
{
   Thread.sleep(4000);
   System.out.println("VAS CONSULTING")
}
catch(InterruptedException e)
{
   //Stop printing out VAS CONSULTING
   return;  /*This will terminate the thread*/
}
```

also if a method that doesn't throw an Interrupted Exception isn't used within the run method
you can do this to handle Thread Interruption or terminate the Thread

```
@Override
public void run()
{

   System.out.println("VAS CONSULTING");
   if(Thread.Interrupted())
   {
     doSomethingElse();//process something else within the thread
    return; //Terminates the current Thread
   }

}
```

I hope this Helps You or Someone Else.

Answer (score 0):

interrupt() method does not stop the Thread.
read this for more detailed explanation http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/