# looking for a way to stop/kill a Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm looking for a way to stop/kill a Thread, i saw that Thread.stop() is deprecated. So i started searching for another solution and saw multiple posts suggesting this:

```
thread.interrupt();
thread = null;
```

But that just won't stop my Thread, my Thread looks like this:

```
public static Thread loadingSpinnerTimer (final Context context, final ImageView imageView){
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while (!isPaused) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            // Write your code here to update the UI.
                            Log.e("ThreadMessage","HasRun");
                            if (ticker == 12){
                                ticker = 0;
                            }
                            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.spinner_160x160);
                            Bitmap img = Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); //ARGB_8888 transparrent?
                            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(img);
                            int offset = myBitmap.getWidth()*ticker;
                            Rect srcrectangle = new Rect( 0, offset, myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getWidth()+offset);
                            Rect dstrectangle = new Rect( 0, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getWidth());
                            canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap,srcrectangle,dstrectangle,null);
                            img.setHeight(myBitmap.getWidth());
                            imageView.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), img));
                            ticker++;
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
    return thread;
}
```

Anyone get a solution i can use to stop/kill my Thread? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: check [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html)

Comment: see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20528033/4101719)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a while loop and checking `isPaused` and then catching the general `Exception` at the end of the loop. Even if the `InterruptedException` is thrown, it will be caught and then re-run the while loop again.

You will need to change the `isPaused` to true when you catch the `InterruptedException` exception so that the while loop will stop running.

Answer (score 0):

Since you periodically execute a task, a good solution is to use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

Then the scheduled task can be elegantly stopped calling `cancel()` on the `ScheduledFuture<?>`:

```
final Runnable handlerRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do same work as before
    }
};
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
ScheduledFuture<?> sf = ses.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mHandler.post(handlerRunnable);
    }
}, 0, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); // execute every 100ms

// stop
sf.cancel();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `thread.interrupt()`; you should occasionally check if your `Thread` was interupted using something like:

```
if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
   return;
}
```

Note that checking this flag resets it; so that if you ever check for this flag your should either:

Terminate your thread

1. List item
2. Throw an InterruptedException
3. Reset the flag by calling `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();`