# Why we use a flag to stop a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

When I tried to figure out how to stop a thread in a program with multiple threads,
I was [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961714/how-to-properly-stop-the-thread-in-java) to call a method which actually sets a flag to tell that thread stop doing real works,like this:

```
public class ThreadTobeTerminated implements Runnable {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IndexProcessor.class);
    private volatile boolean running = true;

    public void terminate() {
        running = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            try {
                LOGGER.debug("Doing some real work ,like Counting...");
                for(int i=0;i<100;i++){}

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Exception", e);
                running = false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

when I want to stop this tread ,I'll call `threadInstance.terminate();`.

Don't I need to literally stop this thread ?

Why I should leave this thread to do some useless work (method `run` called ,test the flag `running==false` then return)?  I mean :**this is a waste of time** ,isn't it?

Comment: What do you propose as an alternative, that still allows the thread to stop in a *controlled* manner, instead of potentially half-way through an operation, leaving the system in a less well-defined state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the execution scope goes beyond the `run()` method, the thread stops, so the moment that the `while` loop is broken, the thread will stop.

This would also allow you to do some clean up if the situation requires it:

```
public void run() {
    while (running) {
        try {
            LOGGER.debug("Doing some real work ,like Counting...");
            for(int i=0;i<100;i++){}

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception", e);
            running = false;
        }           
    }
    //Clean up
}
```

The above approach allows you some control over how is the thread stops *and what happens after* as opposed to potentially just kill it, which could cause all kinds of problems.