# Stop running Thread By Name

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a `multithreaded` application and I assign a unique name to each thread through `setName()` property.

Now, I want functionality to get access to the threads directly with their corresponding name to stop it.

How can i get that?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Thread.currentThread().getName();

Comment: And what did you try to stop the thread by his name?

Comment: Why don't you just keep a reference to the threads or use signals for the threads to stop themselves?

Answer (score 1):

To find a thread you use this: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ThreadUtils.html (https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/ThreadUtils.java)

But that gives you only a reference to the thread and you cannot simply terminate it (stop() is deprecated). Depending on what the Thread is doing maybe interrupting it is an option?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to get to the thread (by its name) to call `Thread.stop()` on it. If that is the case - don't do that. The method is deprecated - [see why](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961714/how-to-properly-stop-the-thread-in-java) has some suggestions on how to properly stop a thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to access a thread by name and you don't have a reference that can be used, you could use [`ThreadGroup`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html) and search the tree formed by groups and threads for the one with the correct name.

From the JavaDoc:

> A thread group represents a set of threads. In addition, a thread group can also include other thread groups. The thread groups form a tree in which every thread group except the initial thread group has a parent.

Thus you should be able to call `Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup()`, use `getParent()` to find the initial/root group, list all active threads using `enumerate(Thread[])` and search the threads.

Comment: the enumerate(Thread[]) API is tricky, see https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/ThreadUtils.java

Comment: @salyh Yeah, that's why I like your `ThreadUtils` suggestion better :)