# How can I stop the Thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to start a Thread (in Java). This Thread should be to execute every 5 minutes. This Thread, start the method, if the method return true, I want to stop the Thread. I'm not able to do this.
This is my code:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(); 
timer.schedule( new TimerTask() 
{ 
    public void run() { 
     verificaAssistenza ass = new verificaAssistenza();
     if(ass.checkAssistenza())
     //I WANT TO STOP THE THREAD
    } 
}, 0, 60*(1000*1));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly stop the Thread in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961714/how-to-properly-stop-the-thread-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just cancel the TimerTask

```
if (ass.checkAssistenza()) {
    cancel();
    return;
}
```

From the Javadoc:

> Cancels this timer task. If the task has been scheduled for one-time
>   execution and has not yet run, or has not yet been scheduled, it will
>   never run. If the task has been scheduled for repeated execution, it
>   will never run again. (If the task is running when this call occurs,
>   the task will run to completion, but will never run again.)

If the Timer has only one timerTask call cancel on the Timer itself:

```
final Timer timer = new Timer(); 

    ...
    if (ass.checkAssistenza()) {
        timer.cancel();
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
timer.cancel();
timer.purge();
```

the Doc from [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html):

> **cancel**()
>   Terminates this timer, discarding any currently scheduled tasks.

and

> **purge**() Removes all cancelled tasks from this timer's task queue.