# Will all threads be killed when a service stopped?

Tags: android, service

In the `onStartCommand()` method of my service, I start a long-running thread.

The service is started in my `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()`.

When my application quit (the time Main Activity closed by user), I stop the service. But I want to ensure that the thread mentioned before has been killed, or I have to stop the thread before/after that.

So will all threads **started in a service** be killed automatically when the service stopped?

Comment: No they won't be killed. If you want to manually kill it you have to have some check points. Refer Async Tasks.

Comment: Do a Log.d() inside the long running thread  you would find out for yourself !

Comment: Threads are component independant. By component I mean Activity, Service, Content Providers and Broadcast Receivers. By independant, I mean they are not responding to lifecycle callback method such as onCreate, onDestroy, etc.

Comment: So I wonder is it necessary to wrap a daemon thread (or a thread works like a daemon) in a service, and why? @AlexandreMartin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just checked this by logging the thread's state in my service's `onDestroy()`. The thread remains alive after my service stopped.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961714/how-to-properly-stop-the-thread-in-java

Comment: Thank you. But my thread runs a web server (Jetty). I could stop it just by calling the server's `stop()` method. @GennadiiSaprykin

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
     super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    Log.d(TAG,"Service started..")

    Thread(Runnable {
        for (i in 1..1000){
            Thread.sleep(3000)
            serviceRandom = i;
            Log.d(TAG,"Service Random - "+serviceRandom)
        }
    }).start()

    return Service.START_STICKY
}
```

This is a simple way to find out if thread keeps alive or stops after service stopped by calling

> stopService(serviceIntent)

from Activity.

in logcat you will observe count incrementing logs. That means we have to stop it on our own.