# Ignite put data into a cache asynchronosuly

Tags: java, asynchronous, future

Im working on a heavy loaded application and would like to have the ability to put data into a cache asynchronously. I mean something like invoke the operation on a cache and receive `IgniteFuture<V>` representing the result.

I mean I need the ability to paralelize data extraction from a persistence storage and putting them into a cache. If something happen I can try to extract the data once more (fine not too much of data, quite fine grained).

Comment: What is your question? It looks like you made an introduction but forgot the last part with the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have any hard requirement on `IgniteFuture` (*which I believe should not be the case*) and all you want is some mechanism to put data into a cache and get it processed asynchronously, and then process the results returned by that operation, then you can use [Java's Executor Service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

If you are not much aware of Java's executor service then you may want to read documentation or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43637049/how-to-store-threads-in-a-multi-threaded-application/43639900#43639900) which highlights quick points, in below example I have also added comments.

Below are few other quick points about number of threads:

- This example creates a `ExecutorService` with "`ThreadPoolExecutor`" implementation, there are other options like "`Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`" and "`Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)`" which lets you define how many threads you want in the JVM.
- You can also choose to directly create object of `ThreadPoolExecutor` like this `return new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());` and you can have more control on how many threads and type of queue. You will need to read more on this if you want to create `ThreadPoolExecutor` object yourself and not through `ExecutorService`

Few other points related to your implementations:

- When you are processing the `Future` objects then it is blocking process, because `Future.get()` is  a blocking call, so your main thread will be blocked until all Future objects are returned and processed.
- If you do not want blocking then there are several options like you can create a new thread to do all this processing and hence freeing your main thread. Another option could be that do not processing Future objects, so as soon you do `executorService.submit(callableTask1)`, you thread will be free, and then in your `CallableTask` object you can push the result in a queue (you can choose [Java's queue implementation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) as per your need) and then process that queue from other thread. Yet another option could be to dedicate another thread for processing your Future objects.

**Sample code:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class ExecutorServiceFutureCallableExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        List<Future<String>> futuresList = new ArrayList<>();

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        ExecutorServiceFutureCallableExample.CallableTask callableTask1 = new ExecutorServiceFutureCallableExample.CallableTask(2000);
        ExecutorServiceFutureCallableExample.CallableTask callableTask2 = new ExecutorServiceFutureCallableExample.CallableTask(1000);
        ExecutorServiceFutureCallableExample.CallableTask callableTask3 = new ExecutorServiceFutureCallableExample.CallableTask(3000);

        System.out.println("### Starting submitting tasks");

        // submit the callable and register the returned future object so that it can be processed later.
        futuresList.add(executorService.submit(callableTask1));
        futuresList.add(executorService.submit(callableTask2));
        futuresList.add(executorService.submit(callableTask3));

        System.out.println("### Finished submitting tasks");

        for (int i = 0; i < futuresList.size(); i++) {
            // here "get()" waits for the future tasks to be returned.
            System.out.println(futuresList.get(i).get());
        }

        System.out.println("### Finished.");
    }

    static class CallableTask implements Callable<String>{

        private long timeToSleep;

        CallableTask(long _timeToSleep){
            this.timeToSleep = _timeToSleep;
        }

        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            String str = new Date() + ": Processing - " + this.hashCode() + " | " + Thread.currentThread() + ", slept for seconds - " + timeToSleep; 
            System.out.println(str);
            Thread.sleep(timeToSleep);
            return str + " ||||| completed at: " + new Date();
        }

        public long getTimeToSleep() {
            return timeToSleep;
        }

        public void setTimeToSleep(long timeToSleep) {
            this.timeToSleep = timeToSleep;
        }

    }
}
```