# Why doesn't finish(); end a Mediaplayer?

Tags: android

Well, why doesn't it?

From my understanding, finish() destroys the entire activity, so it should also destroy the running media player.

Here is my code:

```
MediaPlayer ourSong;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hungat);
    ourSong.start();
    Thread timer = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(5000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                Intent i1 = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY");
                startActivity(i1);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

}

Comment: Because you should call stop() on the MediaPlayer, not rely on GC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `finish()` it won't run until control is returned to Android.
Since you are not stopping the `MediaPlayer` instance, control is not passed.

Stop and release it prior to finishing your activity, and include `onDestroy()` so that its disposed-of properly if activity closes.

For more information, check the official [API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html).

```
MediaPlayer ourSong;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hungat);
    ourSong.start();

    Thread timer = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                destroyMediaPlayer();
            }finally {
                Intent i1 = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY");
                startActivity(i1);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    destroyMediaPlayer();
    finish();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onPause();
    destroyMediaPlayer();
    finish();
}

private void destroyMediaPlayer(){
    if(ourSong != null){
      ourSong.stop();
      ourSong.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe...Edit your answer again and replace mediaPlayer by ourSong...Your code do not compile with provided example

Comment: Why do you have to use stop and release? Can't you just use release?

Comment: @PrimacAntonie Technically you don't need to call stop prior to release, API states that release can be called on `any` state.

Answer (score 0):

The `MediaPlayer` is not connected to the activity and has no idea that the activity is being destroyed. Hence, the `MediaPlayer` is not affected by the activity being destroyed and continues doing whatever you told it to do.

In part, that is because a `MediaPlayer` does not need an activity -- many times, a `MediaPlayer` is managed by a service, because media playback should proceed independently from what the user does with the UI.

You are welcome to arrange yourself to stop the `MediaPlayer` when the activity is destroyed — as others noted, `stop()` and `release()` the `MediaPlayer` in `onDestroy()`. However, *you have to do that yourself*, as otherwise `MediaPlayer` has no way to know that it is supposed to stop.

Comment: Thanks. This is the answer I was looking for. I didn't know it wasn't really a part of the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a thread

use  this
                 runnable.terminate();
                 thread.join();

refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961714/how-to-properly-stop-the-thread-in-java)