# How do I properly stop the thread when a JNI code error occurs?

Tags: java, error-handling, java-native-interface

I have seen the [How to properly stop the Thread in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961714/how-to-properly-stop-the-thread-in-java).
But there is no try&catch in C.

I call a JNI function in a thread. I want to stop the thread when something goes wrong.

What should I do in `error()` to prevent the code behind and stop the thread?

When I call error() in function 1, how to avoid subsequent function execution？

My code like this:

```
new Thread() (new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JNIfunction();
        }
    }).start();
```

JNIfunction():

```
while(flag) {
    //Function1， call error() to stop thread when wrong.
    //Function2， call error() to stop thread when wrong.
    //Function3， call error() to stop thread when wrong.
    ...
}
```

error():

```
void error() {
    flag= 0;
}
```

Comment: I called exit() in error(), which will close the JVM directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `boolean volatile` variable to track in case of error and then stop thread by using `interrupt()`. 
Similar kind of question is answered in detail [How to properly stop the Thread in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961714/how-to-properly-stop-the-thread-in-java)

Comment: I have seen that question.There is no try&catch in C.
When I call error() in function 1, how to avoid subsequent function execution？

Comment: Check if you have got expected value in returned object from C call, else set boolean volatile variable true to stop the flow, call interrupt() and throw custom exception from your error(). I am asking to check status at every C call, thus subsequent executions can be avoided.

Comment: Thank you. I finally used setjmp/longjmp to simulate try/catch in c.

Comment: @loRe Please provide code you have used and mark it as accepted answer, it would be helpful for others, it can also be checked for enhancement if any required.

Comment: in JNIFunciton:

    flag = 0==setjmp(return_buf);

while(flag) {
    //Function1， call error() to stop thread when wrong.
    //Function2， call error() to stop thread when wrong.
    //Function3， call error() to stop thread when wrong.
    ...
}

function error():

void error() {
    longjmp(return_buf, 1);
}

Comment: It seems that i can't format the code in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Set `flag=0`. It will exit the loop and the thread will end naturally.

Comment: When I call error() in function 1, how to avoid subsequent function execution？

Comment: `if (flag==0) break;`

Comment: Can't break in funciton...