# How to stop a thread spawned from a servlet in weblogic container?

Tags: java, multithreading, weblogic

I am loading a servlet on start-up in Weblogic container, from which I am spawning a thread which I want to run continuously until the application is up. However on stopping or deleting the application from container is not stopping the spawned thread. Can I please have any suggestion on how to stop this thread on stopping the application. My application is on Java-8.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single `Thread` you should use a volatile flag as explained in [this flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10961760/1602555).

You can take it a step further by switching to `ExecutorService` to spawn your worker threads and call [`ExecutorService.shutdown()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()) on the application shutdown. If you don't require a graceful shutdown you can use [`ExecutorService.shutdownNow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow()) and set [`Thread.setDaemon(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon(boolean)) flag when creating threads.

Do note that WebLogic server offers a manager to work with server thread pools as per [Using Work Managers to Optimize Scheduled Work](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/CNFGD/self_tuned.htm). If your application is tightly coupled to WebLogic server you might want to use a server thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

Used ServletContextListener instead of plain HttpServlet. Used the contextInitialized() and contextDestroyed() methods for starting and stopping the thread on application start-up and shutdown respectively.

As suggested, I have used ExecutorService for spawning threads.