# Is there any method to force stop or kill a running thread in threading in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm using Threading module in python to create a new thread . I know how to start a Thread and how to join
but I don't know how to terminate it while running.
So Any method to terminate or force stop a thread while running ?

Comment: Are you trying to kill the thread from another thread?

Comment: @Mike67 nope from the main thread

Comment: Check this article: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-different-ways-to-kill-a-thread/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly stop the Thread in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961714/how-to-properly-stop-the-thread-in-java)