# Can a Java Thread be alive more than once?

Tags: java, multithreading

Ok.... Let me try to explain this the best I can....
Also: this is for a mod within minecraft.
Okay, so I created a thread object

```
public static Thread KillThread = new Thread();
```

Then in the constructor of my main class which is called when the game(Mine craft starts) I have

```
KillThread = new Thread(new KillAuraThread());
```

KillAuraThread is the name of the class that is the thread..
So I created a thread now. Is where it's pissing me off
The thread will run for exactly 1 second, and It can not be running multiple times or it will ruin the point of the delaying and threading.

```
if(KillAura.enabled && !KillThread.isAlive())
    {
        System.out.println("Go AURA!");
        try
        {
            KillThread.start();
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

That is called every tick within the game where it would send position updates and such.

Now here is where I'm having the problem. Once the thread starts it becomes "alive" and when it ends it is no longer "alive". But can threads only be started once? because after the first run it's no longer working? And ideas? Links?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881714/how-to-start-stop-restart-a-thread-in-java

Comment: (Perhaps there is a better approach here than threads?)

Comment: Don't use threads.  Minecraft is resource intensive enough without adding tons of threads to run for one second and stop.  Do it the same way everything else does, which is give it a lifetime counter, decrease it by one every tick, and when it gets to zero, kill the aura.

Comment: KillAuraThread is a Runnable interface ?

Comment: You should just hop on irc.esper.net and visit #risucraft .  It's significantly more specialized than SO.

Comment: Also, starting a thread in a constructor is common cause of concurrency bugs.

Comment: Err.. why the continual thread start anyway?  What's wrong with a while loop with a Wait at the top?  When you want to kill the Aura, Notify() it.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7):

Yes Threads can only be started once, you cannot reuse a Thread object.

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a
>   thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution. See [`java.lang.Thread.start()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29)

Regardless of this fact, do not use the `Thread.State` for thread lifecycle management.

Comment: Wow, okay thanks this helps a lot... I'll have to find a new way to do this. And thanks wug, I'll try to do this with out a thread

Answer (score 5):

You're right, threads can run only once and it's [illegal to start/run  a thread more than once](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29). You should consider using a `while` loop to keep your thread alive.

Instead of directly dealing with Threads, you should be using the classes inside the `java.util.concurrent` package to schedule a fixed task at regular intervals which is apparently what you're trying to do. Take a look at [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).

Comment: +1 for the while loop.  A Wait() at the top of the loop should work - just Notify() it when you want to kill the Aura.