# Running the more than two threads in a particular order

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I want the threads to run in a particular order. Suppose I have three thread **T1, T2, T2** .

**T1 prints 0**
**T2 prints 1**
**T3 prints 2**

I want the output in the order ***0 1 2***, **0 1 2** for certain number of time.

If there are two threads **T1** and **T2**. Printing **0 1, 0 1...** can be done using **Producer-Consumer Problem** using `synchronization`.

Comment: You've actually asked an answer.

Comment: This is possible, but not especially convenient, and the reason is that it is a rather senseless thing to ask concurrent threads to do.

Comment: Yes I am looking for possible. Not for convenient.

Comment: @maroun I have tried with two thread. Using the synchronization. But when I am adding one more thread synchronization is going out of toss.

Comment: Actually, synchronization alone can't work even for two threads. It just happened to work for you.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik :: For your reference using synchronization when there is two thread http://www.javatechtipssharedbygaurav.com/2013/05/producer-consumer-problem-in-java.html

Comment: No useful information at that site... it uses way more than synchronization, just as I implied above. The same basic elements can be used to coordinate *any number of threads*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class UnitOfWork:

```
public class UnitOfWork implements Runnable
{
    String text;

    public UnitOfWork(String text){
        this.text = text;
    }

    public void run(){
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

And then create a single thread executor service:

```
ExecutorService executor = ExecutorService.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

which you will use like this:

```
UnitOfWork uow0 = new UnitOfWork("0");
UnitOfWork uow1 = new UnitOfWork("1");
UnitOfWork uow2 = new UnitOfWork("2");

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    executor.submit(uow0);
    executor.submit(uow1);
    executor.submit(uow2);
}
```

When you are unhappy with the single thread, you can start using multiple thread executor service, which will in fact run tasks concurrently.

Comment: OP, if this is all you asked for, then you didn't need any threads, just as indicated to you above. `executor.submit()` in this case just directly calls `UnitOfWork.run()`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik nope, SingleThreadExecutor creates a new thread, which will not change, to execute all the task. I have a working app that relies on this fact.

Comment: Yes, you are right---you hand over the task to the other thread, and the work of *that* thread is just calling `run` of all the submitted tasks in turn. Unless you need the main thread to do something else, that fact is just overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Using the method join() in the thread class you can achieve this.

The join method allows one thread to wait for the completion of another. If t is a Thread object whose thread is currently executing,

t.join();

causes the current thread to pause execution until t's thread terminates. Overloads of join allow the programmer to specify a waiting period. However, as with sleep, join is dependent on the OS for timing, so you should not assume that join will wait exactly as long as you specify.

Like sleep, join responds to an interrupt by exiting with an InterruptedException.

Comment: look google did it http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html

Comment: @Juan `join` certain that until the threads terminates another should wait.

Comment: @Pradeep I don't understand your comment. But yes if you use threads and you want a particular order in execution you need to join them, otherwise there's no guarantee that the finish order would be the required one.

Comment: OP doesn't wath the threads to *finish* in order, but to *print* in order.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik I don't see the conflict, none of us knows what the duration is or the process implications that each thread has.

Comment: Actually, everybody who has read the question knows it: "I want the output in the order 0 1 2, 0 1 2 for certain number of time." Each thread has its own digit to print -> draw your conclusion from there.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik, that's the result expected for each thread. It doesn't make any sense to create three threads just to print numbers, is reasonably to assume there's something more envolved in the process. Yet I stand by my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use *Thread.join* to ensure it terminates before the next thread starts.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final Thread th1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 1000));
                    System.out.println("Thread 1");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        Thread th2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 1000));
                    System.out.println("Thread 2");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        Thread th3 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 1000));
                    System.out.println("Thread 3");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        th1.start();
        th1.join();
        th2.start();
        th2.join();
        th3.start();
    }
```

Comment: I want the output repeatedly for a certain number of time. It gives the output only once.

Comment: Then surround the last 5 lines with a cycle

Comment: It will not work it will throw `IllegalThreadStateException`. Once thread is terminated it can't be start again.

Comment: @PradeepKrKaushal http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881714/how-to-start-stop-restart-a-thread-in-java

Comment: @JuanManuel does not fit with my question.

Comment: @PradeepKrKaushal yes it does, you just don't know it yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is a minimalist piece of code which does *literally* what you asked for. It relies on the `wait-notify` mechanism.

I stand by my assesment that you do not need any threads to meet your requirement. A simple loop which prints 0-1-2 is all you really need.

```
import static java.lang.Thread.currentThread;

public class A {
  static int coordinator, timesPrinted;
  static final int numThreads = 3, timesToPrint = 300;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
      final int myId = i;
      new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run() {
        while (true) synchronized (A.class) {
          if (coordinator%numThreads == myId) {
            System.out.println(myId+1);
            coordinator++;
            if (timesPrinted++ > timesToPrint) currentThread().interrupt();
            A.class.notifyAll();
          }
          try {A.class.wait();} catch (InterruptedException e) {break;}
        }
      }}).start();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Marko Topolnik for your reply. It was not just about the printing the number. Try to see the question in different perspective.Just for scenario it's like one thread output will be the input for the next thread.

Comment: Sure, I didn't think it was just about numbers---but whenever you have such an ordering constraint on threads, then it makes no sense to have the threads in the first place. You need one thread which executes the tasks in order. Whether or not you need even that one thread in addition to some "main" thread is still open---if you really do, then Jakub's solution is the right choice. If not, then you don't even need an executor service involved.